# Maven: Eclipse cdt library

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-cdt

I want to use the eclipse CDT in my java application however I am not sure how to include it into my application. I am hoping on using maven/gradle to do this.

Is there a way to include the org.eclipse.cdt using the maven repository?

The reason I am asking about a maven build is that I do not want to store a jar in the version control system.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem... can you please tell me what was your solution? Thanks

Comment: There is no maven repository for this unfortunately, you will have to download the jar and include it in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All downloads are provided under the terms and conditions of the
>   [Eclipse Foundation Software User Agreement](https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl/notice.php) unless otherwise specified.
>
> The CDT can either be installed as part of the Eclipse C/C++ IDE
>   packaged zip file or installed into an existing Eclipse using the
>   "Install New Software..." dialog and entering the p2 repository URLs
>   listed below.
>
> CDT also provides its debugger as a stand-alone RCP application which
>   can be downloaded and installed on its own. You can find more
>   information about the Stand-alone Debugger on the Wiki.

So, the maven repository does not have this library. You can download this library from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php).

Comment: Why have you quoted the "The CDT Project provides a fully functional C and C++ Integrated Development Environment based on the Eclipse platform"? I cannot see the relation between that quote and the conclusion of the maven does not have this library. Could you further explain please

Comment: Sorry, my quoted is not clearly. I will update this.